# Updating a MySQL Field when a checkbox is clicked using jQuery, AJAX and PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I need a checkbox to update a MySQL field from a 1 to 0 and vice versa when clicked. I want to use jQuery/AJAX and PHP to do this so I do not have to have the page re-loaded. I placed the code below but I cannot get it to work. I feel that I am very close.

Note: I know `mysql_query` is deprecated. This is an older project and I will be converting it soon but need this to work for now.

The form:

```
if($list_row['online'] == 0) {
    echo '<input type="checkbox" name="online" id="' . $list_row['id'] . '" data-toggle="toggle" checked>&nbsp;';
} else {
    echo '<input type="checkbox" name="online" id="' . $list_row['id'] . '" data-toggle="toggle">&nbsp;';

                        }
```

The jQuery:

```
 <script>
$('.online').mousedown(function() {

    var id    = $(this).attr('id');

    if($(this).attr('checked')) {
        var online = 1;
    } else {
        var online = 0;
    }

    $.ajax({
        type:'GET',
        url:'processes/process_item_online.php?',
        data:'id= ' + id + '&online='+online
    });

 });
 </script>
```

The PHP:

```
include '../connect.php';

// START IF LOGGED IN
  session_start();

if (!isset($_SESSION['is_logged_in'])) {

    header("location: login.php");

} else {

    $login = true;

}


 $id = $_GET['id'];
 $online = $_GET['online'];

 mysql_query("UPDATE `store_items` SET online=$online WHERE id='$id'");
```

Comment: Have you watched the AJAX request / response in the browser's developer tools? Have you included the jQuery library in the project? Are there any errors reported? Are you running this on a web-server?

Comment: I have jQuery included, running on Apache server, No errors in the Chrome console log.

Comment: Have you watched the request/response?

Comment: How would I access that in Chrome?

Comment: The Network tab in the developer tools. Send the AJAX request and you'll see the process on the left. Click on the process and you'll have some other tabs available to you (Headers, Preview, Response, Cookies, Timing) depending on the Chrome version.

Comment: I just checked it and there is no activity at all.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116222/discussion-between-mike-barbaro-and-jay-blanchard).

Comment: So you're not capturing the mousdown evetnt?

Comment: No it's not showing at all.

Comment: I have joined the chat.

Comment: `.online` is a class call, not a `name`. Try `$('input[name="online"')`. https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/ This also is going to be open to SQL injections once the AJAX is working.

Comment: It is behind a login.

Comment: Registered users can still inject you.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved by using the `$(document).ready(function() {` code before the jquery.

Comment: You have another problem - SQL injection. This is quite a serious vuln - your users can reset any of your `store_items` columns to any value of their choosing. Don't go live with this just yet!